# preg_match different behaviours between PHP versions

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to validate the format of an address here in France.
This is the kind of format that I am expecting :

```
5 street name
35230 Village
```

So we have a road address with an optional number, followed with a post code and the name of the village (commune).

On my dev server I am running PHP v5.2.5.

This code line is working

```
$AdOk = preg_match("/^([0-9a-zA-Z-, '\\n]+)(\\d{5})([, ]+)([0-9a-zA-Z-, '\\n]+)$/iu", $ClientAddress);
```

However, when I run it on my production server it fails.

The PHP version in production is v5.3.19

Can anyone help me fix this ?

By the way, I will need to add in accented characters also !

Comment: First thing to do is upgrade your dev box. There's no excust to be running 5.2 these days on any environment -- it's been unsupported for two years.

Comment: try this `/^([\da-z, '\n-]+)(\d{5})([, ]+)([\da-z, '\n-]+)$/iu` you had the `-` in the wrong place so it was denoting a range instead of the character, also you had unnecessary escapes.

Comment: You are quite probably right, however I need to fix this before going through an upgrade of my dev environment as that could potentially cause other problems

Comment: @crypticツ, thankyou for this.  However, whilst it works great on my dev server, on production it still fails.

Comment: @Simon - if the prod server is already on 5.3, what potential problems could possibly happen by upgrading dev to match? I would say that problems are more likely if you don't upgrade - in fact, this question demonstrates my point perfectly. If you don't upgrade you'll still have those problems on prod anyway, so surely it's better to find them on dev first where you can at least find them before the customers get to see them, and work to fix with them without worrying about it being a production system.

Comment: I don't agree with you see  : http://3v4l.org/NKm0r  and why are you using `PHP 5.2` in the first place

Comment: @Baba, I am using Apache 2.2.9 on a windows system.  Upgrading to 5.3.19 requires a reinstall of Apache also so as to use the VC9 binaries - thats why

Comment: What is wrong with re installing Apache ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact the problem arose with the use of a single quote.

This was received by the script as \' and the slash was causing the test to fail.

Comment: Can you explain more closely? This should not happen with the code you show in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: `'/^([\da-z\-,\'\s]+)(\d{5})([,\s]+)([\da-z\-,\'\s]+)$/iu'`. This one is using single quote and I use \s instead of space and new line. Please let me know the result between both server.